# Generic JSON Support

Tags: scala, generics, spray, akka-http, spray-json

How do you use RootJsonFormat with Generics?

Do I have to **copy paste** every possibility like this:

```
trait IDJsonSupport
  extends SprayJsonSupport
    with DefaultJsonProtocol{

  implicit object AddressIDFormat extends RootJsonFormat[ID[Address]] {
    override def write(obj: ID[Address]): JsValue = JsNumber(obj.value)
    override def read(json: JsValue): ID[Address] = json match {
      case JsNumber(id) => new ID[Address](id.toLongExact)
      case _ => deserializationError("Address ID expected")
    }
  }

  implicit object CompanyIDFormat extends RootJsonFormat[ID[Company]] {
    override def write(obj: ID[Company]): JsValue = JsNumber(obj.value)
    override def read(json: JsValue): ID[Company] = json match {
      case JsNumber(id) => new ID[Company](id.toLongExact)
      case _ => deserializationError("Company ID expected")
    }
  }

  implicit object NoteIDFormat extends RootJsonFormat[ID[Note]] {
    override def write(obj: ID[Note]): JsValue = JsNumber(obj.value)
    override def read(json: JsValue): ID[Note] = json match {
      case JsNumber(id) => new ID[Note](id.toLongExact)
      case _ => deserializationError("Note ID expected")
    }
  }

  ...
```

?

This:

```
implicit object AnyIDFormat extends RootJsonFormat[ID[_]] { ... }
```

does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I assume `ID` class is defined like this:

```
case class ID[T](value: Long)
```

If so, you can define a generic format `implicit def` and specific formats will be automatically created by Scala compiler.

```
implicit def genericIDFormat[T]: RootJsonFormat[ID[T]] = new RootJsonFormat[ID[T]] {
  override def write(obj: ID[T]): JsValue = JsNumber(obj.value)
  override def read(json: JsValue): ID[T] = json match {
    case JsNumber(id) => ID(id.toLongExact)
    case _ => deserializationError("ID expected")
  }
}
```